# uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=1/n^x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Consider the sequence of functions:
\begin{align}
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^x}.
\end{align}

Does $(f_n)_n$ converge uniformaly on $[0,\infty)$. I proved via the Cauchy criterion that $(f_n)_n$ can not converge uniformaly on $(-\infty, 0)$, but unfortunately could not study the uniform convergence on $[0,\infty)$.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For any $x>0$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-x}=0$.  But for $x=0$, $n^{-x}=1$.  Does that help?

Comment: This is obvious but sorry, I didn`t get what you mean. Can you clarify please. @MarkViola

Comment: If a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly, then the limit function is continuous.   So, is it continuous?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it converges uniformly on $ [0, \infty) $. Because if it does then we have
$$  \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to 0^+} f_n(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{n \to \infty}  f_n(x). $$
But a direct computation shows that the left hand side is 1 while the right hand side is 0, hence a contradiction.

Comment: Why this equality?. Is this a consequence of the uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes. If the function converges uniformly on a certain domain, then you can switch the limits.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't even converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.  Suppose by way of contradiction that it does, let $\epsilon>0$ be given, then there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|\frac{1}{n^{x}}|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.  Take $x=-\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(N)}$ and pick $n=N$, then $\frac{1}{n^{x}}=\epsilon$ (needs to be strictly less than $\epsilon$).  Contradiction.